# Not sure whether I have syntax errors or errors with the code

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently creating a dice game where you roll two dice and the javascript decides whether you won lost or tied with the computer. It is simple code, but I am unsure as to if I have made a syntax error or the code itself.

I have already tried looking over the code, but I am fairly new to this and some professional eyes would be useful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title> Game of dice </title>
<script> 

var player;
var computer;

function randDice() {
var number = randNum(1,6);  
return number;
}

function rollDice(){


player = randDice();
computer = randDice();


if (player == 1) {
document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die1.png"
} else if (player == 2) {
document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die2.png"
} else if (player == 3) {
document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die3.png"
} else if (player == 4) {
document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die4.png"                    
} else if (player == 5) {
document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die5.png"
} else (player == 6) {
document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die6.png"   

if (computer == 1) {
document.getElementById("dieTwo").src= "die1.png"
} else if (computer == 2) {
document.getElementById("dieTwo").src= "die2.png"
} else if (computer == 3) {
document.getElementById("dieTwo").src= "die3.png"
} else if (computer == 4) {
document.getElementById("dieTwo").src= "die4.png"
} else if (computer == 5) {
document.getElementById("dieTwo").src= "die5.png"
} else (computer == 6) {
document.getElementById("dieTwo").src= "die6.png"
checkWin();
}
function checkWin(){

if (player == computer){
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "You tied";
} else if (player > computer){
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "You-won!";
} else (player < computer){
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "You-lost";
}
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1> Die roll </h1>
<img src="die1.png" id="dieOne"><image>
<img src="die2.png" id="dieTwo"><image>
<br>
<br>
<button onClick="rollDice();">Roll</button>
<br>
<p id="winner"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you see in the developer tools?

Comment: I only see SyntaxError: unexpected token: '{'

Comment: Look at the line it points to and see why it's wrong.

Comment: First, I think you are missing a bracket `}` after `document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die6.png"`. Second, you could simplify your code with: `document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die" + player + ".png";` and `document.getElementById("dieTwo").src= "die" + computer  + ".png"`. Leaving only `if (computer == 6) { checkWin() }`

Answer (score 1):

There are some error in your source code:

- Missing } in function rollDice
- You wrong else if condition `else (player == 6)`
- Put script tag in head, need move to close body tag.
- Also check refer for randNum() method

You can F12 and see console tab for detail error message at what line of code.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title> Game of dice </title>

</head>

<body>

<h1> Die roll </h1>
<img src="die1.png" id="dieOne"><image>
<img src="die2.png" id="dieTwo"><image>
<br>
<br>
<button onClick="rollDice();">Roll</button>
<br>
<p id="winner"></p>

<script> 

var player;
var computer;

function randDice() {
var number = randNum(1,6);  
return number;
}

function rollDice(){


player = randDice();
computer = randDice();


if (player == 1) {
document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die1.png"
} else if (player == 2) {
document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die2.png"
} else if (player == 3) {
document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die3.png"
} else if (player == 4) {
document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die4.png"                    
} else if (player == 5) {
document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die5.png"
} else if(player == 6) {
document.getElementById("dieOne").src= "die6.png"
}

if (computer == 1) {
document.getElementById("dieTwo").src= "die1.png"
} else if (computer == 2) {
document.getElementById("dieTwo").src= "die2.png"
} else if (computer == 3) {
document.getElementById("dieTwo").src= "die3.png"
} else if (computer == 4) {
document.getElementById("dieTwo").src= "die4.png"
} else if (computer == 5) {
document.getElementById("dieTwo").src= "die5.png"
} else if(computer == 6) {
document.getElementById("dieTwo").src= "die6.png"
checkWin();
}

}
function checkWin(){

if (player == computer){
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "You tied";
} else if (player > computer){
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "You-won!";
} else if(player < computer){
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "You-lost";
}
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i've done this game before  this was my code

```
<html>

<head>

   <script>
    var roll1;

    var roll2;  


       function rollTheDice()
       {  
           roll1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

            document.getElementById('imgDice').src = roll1 + ".jpg";

           return roll1;
       }

        function rollTheDice2()
       {  
            roll2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

            document.getElementById('imgDice2').src = roll2 + "a.jpg";

           return roll2;
       }


            function compareDice()
       {  
         if (roll1 < roll2 ) {alert("You Loose")
             ;
             } else if (roll1 > roll2 )  {
             alert ("You Win")
               ;
               } else {alert ("You Tie")
                ;
                }
    }

   </script>
</head>
<body>


<input type="button"
   onclick="rollTheDice();"
   value="Get Your Die"/>
<img src="" id="imgDice"/>

    <br>

    <input type="button"
   onclick="rollTheDice2();"
   value="Choose Opponent's Die"/>
<img src="" id="imgDice2"/>
    <br>

    <input type="button"
   onclick="compareDice();"
   value="Who wins?"/>
<img src="" id="imgDice"/>



</body>
</html>
```